# abc = ( a!+b!+c!) in c logical error it doesnt show the results or anything

Tags: c

when i compile and run this code, nothing happens what is the problem do you have any idea ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int kontrol(int x,int y)

{   int sonuc;

    if(x==y)

    sonuc=1;

    else

    sonuc=0;

    return sonuc;

}

int main ()

{
    int sayi,a,birler,kontrol1,onlar,onlar1,yuzler,i,bas1=1,bas2=1,bas3=1;

for(a=123;a<1000;a++)

{ 

  birler=a%10;

  onlar1=a%100;

  onlar=onlar1/10;

  yuzler=a/100;

  for(i=1;i<=birler;i++)

   {bas1=i*bas1;

   }

   for(i=1;i<=onlar;i++)

   {bas2=i*bas2;

   }

  for(i=1;i<=yuzler;i++)

   {bas3=i*bas3;

   }

sayi=bas3+bas2+bas1;

kontrol1 = kontrol(sayi, a);

if (kontrol1==1)

printf("%d",a);

}


system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1) This isn't C#. 2) You need to pay more attention to making your posts presentable. 3) You've given more code than you really need in order to demonstrate the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger. Then you can step through the code, line by line, and check for yourself what might be wrong.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to observe what it's doing? I have no idea what it's _supposed_ to do anyway.

Comment: Just one thing: since `x==y` produces the value `0` or `1` (type `int`), the whole `kontrol` function can be eliminated (`kontrol1 = (x==y);`). Take it one step further and eliminate the `kontrol1` variable: `if (x == y) print("%d", a);`

Comment: Ah come on guys, the question title says `abc = a! + b! + c!` and in the loop the decimal digits are extracted and their factorials are computed, so it seems pretty clear what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to initialize `bas1=1; bas2=1; bas3=1;` inside the `for (a...)` loop.